# contact.vcf Vcard does not seems to be a valid business card. Windows phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, vcf-vcard

I create a Vcard (Business Card) in my windows phone 8.1 application. 
mycontact.vcf.

I store that card to my phone memory. When I try to open that alert display that mycontact.vcf does not seems to be a valid business card (Vcard).

While when I open same file in notepad then value data display there. 
I want to open this in windows contact.
My code is here.

```
  var vcf = new StringBuilder();
  vcf.Append("Category:" + currentcontact.title + System.Environment.NewLine);

  StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary; 
  StorageFile sampleFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("mycontact.vcf", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
  await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, vcf.ToString());
```

Is there any problem in creation or any thing else.
I attach screen shot too. 
[image]

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the actual content of your VCF file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are writing is not a vCard at all.

- All vCard files must start with "BEGIN:VCARD" and end with "END:VCARD".
- All vCards must have VERSION property.
- "Category" is not a valid property

I think this is what you want.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
CATEGORIES:...
END:VCARD
```

I take cash or credit.